# VB.net Regular Expressions (Website Extractor)

Tags: vb.net, debugging

I have this so far

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
Dim regx As New Regex("https?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)

Dim mactches As MatchCollection = regx.Matches(Input)
For Each match As Match In mactches
    TbOutput.Text = TbOutput.Replace(match.Value, [String].Format("<a href=""{0}"" target=""_blank"">{0}</a>", match.Value))
Next
```

I was wondering what am I doing wrong. The `TbOutput.Text = TbOutput.Replace` is giving errors, then I put in a `.Split` and didn't work either plus my `regx.Matches(Input)` is giving me an error. The input part is giving me an error. I was wondering if I have to put something else in it.

Comment: What kind of errors?

Comment: What exactly is `Input`? Also, I'm fairly sure the error is mostly because you need `TbOutput.Text.Replace`; textboxes are not strings, and therefore have very few of the same methods. (There's also a typo in the For loop's In, but eh.)